# Rcpp won't install after updating R and RStudio on Mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: rstudio, rcpp

I've just updated R to R3.3.2 and RStudio to 1.0.136. When I attempted to install UsingR package via the Studio Install Packages menu, I got this message:

> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

Trying to use library(UsingR) produces this message.

> library(UsingR)
>   Loading required package: Hmisc
>   Loading required package: ggplot2
>   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
>   Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded

I found some stuff about this online, but far too complicated for me to understand. Anyone have a simple way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect is an error on your end.  You are using R 3.2.3, which is outdated by almost one year as R 3.3.0 came out in April, we are now at R 3.3.2.

R stores all its *binary* packages under a patch with the major.minor. So the *most recent* OS X (binary) version of Rcpp at indexed at CRAN in a patch with 3.3 (see [here])https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/Rcpp_0.12.8.tgz) -- but your version of R will read only at 3.2 so you will not see updated versions.

The easiest fix is to update to R 3.3.2.

Or install manually by downloading from [the Rcpp source URL at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.9.tar.gz) and then pointing at the source -- or doing `install.packages("Rcpp", type="source")`.  You may run into other OS X issues for which you will get help from other questions here -- but this gets you current Rcpp.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I did download R 3.3.2.

Comment: Try installing Rcpp then.  There are some other related questions here wrt different OS X versions.

Comment: Turns out it was updating to Sierra on Mac but not starting Xcode. Once I started Xcode, the install worked.

Comment: As we suspected,  a local issue.